# What is the cause of this seemingly random error that occurs when I start the fish shell?

Tags: macos, fish, macos-bigsur

I'm sorry that I'm asking a question like this here, but I have absolutely no idea what is causing it, and I can't seem to find any information anywhere else. Whenever I launch fish on my computer (Intel Mac running MacOS Big Sur 11.4) I get a long error about a $PATH entry.

```
set: Warning: $PATH entry "/usr/local/opt/fzf/bin:/usr/local/opt/go@1.14/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/opt/go@1.14/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS" is not valid (No such file or directory)
set: Did you mean 'set PATH $PATH /usr/local/opt/go@1.14/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/opt/go@1.14/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Applications/VMware Fusion.app/Contents/Public:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands:/Applications/Wireshark.app/Contents/MacOS'?
```

The only problem I can think of is that Wireshark isn't installed on my computer, but I find that unlikely since it used to be but I uninstalled it a long time ago, and this error just started showing up in the last couple days.

Does anybody know the cause of this error and how I might be able to fix it?

Comment: The directory `/usr/local/opt/fzf/bin` is present in the first line but not the second one. Does this directory exist?

Comment: Note that in fish, PATH is handled specially: it is a **list** in fish, not a colon-separated string. See https://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#path and https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#variables-path

Comment: @gronostaj yes I just confirmed that it exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have recently upgraded to fish 3.3.0, which contains an issue where [`set PATH arg:with:colons` may print a superfluous error](https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/8095). One of the directories in your `set PATH` command - perhaps in your `config.fish`? - does not exist.

This should be fixed in fish 3.3.1, which we hope to have released soon.

Comment: I just checked my fish version and it is fish 3.3.0. I also hope that 3.3.1 gets released soon since it's very annoying to have to look at this error every time I open my terminal. I figured out how to remove the path involving Wireshark at least so hopefully once it does get released this won't be an issue

Comment: Fish just got updated to version 3.3.1 on Homebrew so I have now updated and the issue appears to be resolved. Thank you, and I will mark your answer as correct